# salesforce mult-valued section

Tags: jquery, salesforce

I am wondering if there is a way to capture multi-values with one ID selector if if there is a workaround to make this work. I would like to use checkboxes if at all possible so the user can select up to 4 values. I have looked at the multipick list but can't seem to understand how that works since I don't work on the Saleforce end. I have:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="2092304vE303450" name="2092304vE303450" value="1"> Value 1

 <input type="checkbox" id="2092304vE303450" name="2092304vE303450" value="2"> Value 2

 <input type="checkbox" id="2092304vE303450" name="2092304vE303450" value="3"> Value 3

 <input type="checkbox" id="2092304vE303450" name="2092304vE303450" value="4"> Value 4
```

Comment: You mean something like this(remember that id should be unique): http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/9D8wG/5/

Comment: the problem is it cant be, have to use the same id in salesforce

Comment: How about this(i'm using your same html): http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/9D8wG/6/

Comment: Tell me if it works.

Comment: it doesnt work, it only returns the last id value :(

Answer (score 1):

If you use a Visualforce page, a Multiselect Picklist should work. You just need to have a field with type of "Picklist (Multi-select)". The field will be saved in database as a String with each value separated by a semicolon. A good example could be found here: https://hisrinu.wordpress.com/2011/05/30/custom-multi-select-picklist-field-in-visualforce/

Or you could have a jQuery Plugin like any of these https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/multiselect/